# Add namespace and schemaLocation to specific nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have this input xml:

```
<root>
<someElement>
    <otherNode>blabla</otherNode>
</someElement>
</root>
```

And I want this output xml:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/foo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<someElement xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/foo"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.blabla.com/foo/some.xsd">
    <otherNode>blabla</otherNode>
</someElement>
</root>
```

Can I do that in one XSLT or I need two steps to do that? I´ve obtained putting namespace on root node but I can´t put the attributes of secondary node.

Thanks in advance.

Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two namespace declarations on the `someElement` element in your desired output are redundant because they are already present on the `root` element. There is no way to force an XSLT processor to output redundant namespace declarations.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, this xml worked:

<root xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/foo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.blabla.com/foo/some.xsd">
<someElement>
    <otherNode>blabla</otherNode>
</someElement>
</root>